# Do shortcode in WordPress term description work

Tags: wordpress

i want to run Slider Revolution shortcode like this: `[rev_slider alias="media-carousel-autoplay7"]` in term description, but it is not working and it prints me shortcode in category page. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line in *functions.php*:

```
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

[rev_slider] is probably not a 'shortcode' in WordPress sense.

I encountered this on different plugin, Stream media player. They use the same syntax as shortcodes, but they are actually not.

Try using:

```
apply_filters( 'the_content',' [rev_slider alias="media-carousel-autoplay7"] ');
```

instead of do_shortcode, and see if it helps.